# Windows Phone 8.1: MediaElement not Playing after Frame.Navigate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I started building my own Windows Phone 8.1 App. I implemented a mp3 file. Whenever I implement it on the main page in the XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="GoalHorn" Source="/Sounds/mySound.mp3" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Visible"></MediaElement>
```

I can call it in the source code and start it by

```
GoalHorn.Play()
```

I now wanted to put it on another frame. I used:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ScoredPage)), scorerBox.Text);
```

However, when I want to start the sound on the new frame, nothing is done when calling

```
GoalHorn.Play()
```

I have it in the XAML of the new Frame aswell. When I set the autoplay to "true", it also works on the frame but I can't stop it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when media is not opened/loaded still and .Paly method is called on the media element. Add MediaOpened event handler and call play method in it.

```
<MediaElement MediaOpened="GoalHorn_MediaOpened" x:Name="GoalHorn" Source="/Sounds/mySound.mp3" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Visible"></MediaElement>
```

Event handler

```
private void GoalHorn_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GoalHorn.Play();
}
```